# RegEx Replace string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to normalise a string before I go ahead and parse it. Basically remove any spaces before or after a comma and if two or more commas are only separated by space then replace by a single comma.

```
var r = new Regex(@"(\s*,+\s*)");
var query = r.Replace("my reg, is a   disaster    everytime , i,try ,it,       yep, ,disaster.", ",");
```

The output should be:

```
my reg,is a   disaster    everytime,i,try,it,yep,disaster.
```

but its:

```
my reg,is a   disaster    everytime,i,try,it,yep,,disaster.
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var r = new Regex(@"(\s|,)*,(\s|,)*");
```

Basically, replace any number of commas and spaces with a single comma, where at least one comma exists.

Answer (score 2):

A `non-Regex` solution:

```
var dirty = "my reg, is a   disaster    everytime , i,try ,it,       yep, ,disaster.";
var clean = string.Join(",",
                           dirty.Split(new[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                .Select(x => x.Trim())
                                .Where(x => x.Length > 0));
```

Output:

```
my reg,is a   disaster    everytime,i,try,it,yep,disaster.
```

How it works? Split original string by `","` symbol, throw away empty strings, trim all white spaces from start/end of every string, join non-empty strings using same `","`.

IMO, easier to support than `RegEx`

Answer (score 0):

In the original string there is a space between the two commas (", ,"), but the regex says `,+` which means one or more consecutive commas. Does this work: `(\s*(,\s+)+\s*)`?